# Windows copy command return codes?

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy

I would like to test for the success/failure of a copy in a batch file, but I can't find any documentation on what if any errorlevel codes are returned.  For example

```
copy x y
if %errorlevel%. equ 1. (
    echo Copy x y failed due to ...
    exit /B
) else (
  if %errorlevel% equ 2. (
      echo Copy x y failed due to ...
      exit /B
   )
... etc ...
)
```

Comment: You can quickly find that `copy a.txt a.txt` will return an errorlevel unequal to zero, and `copy a.txt b.txt` will return an errorlevel of zero. But as others pointed out, `xcopy` gives more info. But if you don't need that info, just a success/fail, `copy` is just fine.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'd opt for `xcopy` in this case since the error levels are documented (see [xcopy documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491035.aspx), paraphrased below):

```
Exit code  Description
=========  ===========
    0      Files were copied without error.
    1      No files were found to copy.
    2      The user pressed CTRL+C to terminate xcopy.
    4      Initialization error occurred. There is not
           enough memory or disk space, or you entered
           an invalid drive name or invalid syntax on
           the command line.
    5      Disk write error occurred.
```

In any case, `xcopy` is a far more powerful solution. The [equivalent documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490886.aspx) for `copy` does not document the error levels.

---

As an aside, you may want to rethink your use of the `%errorlevel%` *variable.* It has unexpected results, at least in some versions of Windows, if someone has explicitly done something silly like:

```
set errorlevel=22
```

In those cases, the actual *variable* will be used rather than grabbing the actual error level. The "normal" way of doing this is (in decreasing order since `errorlevel` is a "greater than or equal to" check):

```
if errorlevel 2 (
    echo Copy x y failed due to reason 2
    exit /B

)
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Copy x y failed due to reason 1
    exit /B
)
```

---

In addition, if you are running Win7 or Win Server 2008 or later, you should look into [Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.10).aspx), which is now the preferred mass-copy solution.

Comment: It is easier to do that checking this way: `for %%e in (5 4 3 2 1) do if errorlevel %%e goto reason-%%e` followed by `echo Copy OK`

Comment: @Aacini: you also need to test for negative values of errorlevel, with "if not errorlevel 0" or similar.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: XCOPY does not return a negative errorlevel. The standard is: If executed OK: return 0, if end because any error: return a value greater than 0.

Comment: @Aacini: XCOPY doesn't *deliberately* return a negative errorlevel, but might still do so under unusual circumstances.  Most exception codes are negative when interpreted as a signed integer.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: It is **IMPOSSIBLE** for XCOPY to return a negative errorlevel because the possible range is from 0 to 255 (one byte). Indeed, it is impossible for any external executable file to return a negative errorlevel value in Windows/DOS environment. The only internal cmd.exe command capable to do so is `EXIT /B exitcode` that use a nonstandard, undocumented method to set a 32-bits signed value. However, I will offer you an apology if you show me any documentation on how to return a negative errorlevel (a value larger than a byte) from an executable program in Windows/DOS environment.

Comment: @Aacini: See ExitProcess (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682658%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  DOS has nothing to do with it, by the way; on Windows, XCOPY is a Win32 application, not a DOS application.

Comment: Compile the following Java program `public class testprog{public static void main(String x[]){System.exit(-123);}}` then run it. After that, `echo %errorlevel%` will _indeed_ show -123. Not that all this matters for `xcopy` which is documented to only return 0 or greater, so perhaps the discussion should be taken elsewhere :-)

Comment: @paxdiabo: best practice is to always check for unexpected return values, just in case.  The documentation isn't always right.

Comment: xcopy is deprecated as of Windows Vista http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCOPY#Deprecation

Comment: Edmund, I would rather trust Microsoft's own docs on this than wikipedia - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: @paxdiablo: on Vista, xcopy is definitely deprecated; if you type `xcopy /?` the second line of output reads "NOTE: Xcopy is now deprecated, please use Robocopy."  I don't know if this is still true in Windows 7/8, perhaps it was un-deprecated again. :-)

Comment: Interesting @Harry, no such warning on my Win7 box. Perhaps they _did_ undeprecate it. Maybe an important customer complained (something I've seen at a certain other big company). Still, RoboCopy appears to be a far more flexible solution and it's likely that xcopy is now feature-frozen (in maintenance mode only).

Comment: @Aacini: both can be true: a command can return only positive values but `cmd.exe` may show negative values for the command. Windows uses unsigned 32-bit integer for exit status (DWORD, UINT) in its API but `cmd.exe` can show this unsigned integer as its two's compliment negative value, [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27842166/4279)

Comment: A note for using xcopy: xcopy also returns exit code 4 if the destination file already exists and is in use (i.e. cannot be overwritten).

Answer (score 19):

It might also be worth pointing out that xcopy doesn't always return the error code you expect.

For example when trying to copy multiple files with a wildcard but there are no files to copy you expect a return error code of 1 ("No files were found to copy"), but it actually returns 0 ("Files were copied without error")

```
C:\Users\wilson>mkdir bla

C:\Users\wilson>mkdir blert

C:\Users\wilson>xcopy bla\* blert\
0 File(s) copied

C:\Users\wilson>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0
```

Comment: Mathematical logic: `sum(0) = 0`. Not that there isn't an argument for the reverse, but copying nothing is, imo, definitely not a failure condition: a list of zero operations always succeeds (think LINQ or other SQL queries, it isn't an error if the resultset is empty).

Comment: Yea, I know. Logically, a return code of zero is probably correct. But when you consider the return code description "Files were copied without error" then I would expect a non-zero return code for this situation.

Comment: Maybe xcopy needs a 6th return code: 5 - files were not copied without error. That would take away any confusion, right?

Answer (score 12):

I believe `Copy` only returns 0 for success or 1 for failure.

`XCopy` has documented return codes:

> 0 = Files were copied without error.
>   1 = No files were found to copy.
>   2 = The user pressed CTRL+C to terminate xcopy.
>   4 = Initialization error occurred. There is not enough memory or disk space, or you entered an invalid drive name or invalid syntax on the command line.
>   5 = Disk write error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

There is also one point I would like to emphasize: `xcopy` as well as `robocopy` can only copy files, but they can't rename them.
While looking at the original situation (`copy x y`, which looks like a rename to me), I have the impression that the `copy` command still is the only one suitable for this purpose.

Comment: I didn't realize that.  The `copy x y` was arbitrary, I did not mean to imply renames only.  I've been using the 0 and 1 return codes with copy and they work fine.

Comment: Actually you can rename files with `XCOPY`, I've done with for years with scripts from the past.... `ECHO F | XCOPY /Y /F "C:\Path\OrigFileName.txt" "C:\Path\NewFileName.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

```
Error# Description 
0 No error 
1 Not owner 
2 No such file or directory 
3 Interrupted system call 
4 I/O error 
5 Bad file number 
6 No more processes 
7 Not enough core memory 
8 Permission denied 
9 Bad address 
10 File exists 
11 No such device 
12 Not a directory 
13 Is a directory 
14 File table overflow 
15 Too many open files 
16 File too large 
17 No space left on device 
18 Directory not empty 
999 Unmapped error (ABL default)
```