# How to deal with negative numbers that returncode get from subprocess in Python?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, cmd, subprocess, exit-code

This piece of script in python:

```
cmd = 'installer.exe --install ...' #this works fine, the ... just represent many arguments
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
process.wait()
print(process.returncode)
```

This code works fine in my opinion, the problem is the value of `.returncode`.

The installer.exe is ok, did many test to this, and now i trying to create a script in python to automate a test for many days executing this installer.exe .

The installer.exe return:
- Success is 0;
- Failure and errors are NEGATIVE numbers

I have a specific error that is -307 that installer.exe return. But python when execute `print(process.returncode)` its shows 4294966989 ... How can i deal with negative numbers in python, to show in this case the -307?

I am new to python and the env is win7 32 and python 3.4.

**EDIT: the final code working**
The porpose of this code is to run many simple test:

```
import subprocess, ctypes, datetime, time
nIndex = 0
while 1==1:

   cmd = 'installer.exe --reinstall -n "THING NAME"'
   process = subprocess.Popen( cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE )

   now = datetime.datetime.now()
   ret = ctypes.c_int32( process.wait() ).value
   nIndex = nIndex + 1

   output = str( now ) + ' - ' + str( nIndex ) + ' - ' + 'Ret: ' + str( ret ) + '\n'

   f = open( 'test_result.txt', 'a+' )
   f.write( output )
   f.closed

   print( output )
```

Comment: Note that Windows exit codes are defined as 32-bit *unsigned* integers, so Python is actually doing the correct thing here.

Comment: unrelated: use `returncode = subprocess.call(cmd)` instead of `Popen(cmd).wait()`. Do not use `stdout=PIPE` unless you read from the pipe. Use `stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL` if you want to discard the output. Use string formatting instead of multiple `str()` calls e.g.: `with open('results.txt', 'a') as file: print('{now} - {nIndex} - Ret: {ret}'.format(**vars()), file=file)`

Comment: don't put the solution into the question. Post it as an answer instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using NumPy: view the unsigned 32-bit int, 4294966989, as a signed 32-bit int:

```
In [39]: np.uint32(4294966989).view('int32')
Out[39]: -307
```

Comment: Or `ctypes.c_int32(4294966989).value` in pure Python.

Comment: for this situation i liked the way that @AshwiniChaudhary showed with ctypes ... dont need an extra pack and the output is clean...

Comment: But... thanks everyone, problem solved... and i learned a bit more :)

Comment: @buno.karklis: I agree, I like both AshwiniChaudhary's and Kevin's methods.

Comment: @unutbu: no, `cmd.exe` treats them as signed integers (because that's the only kind of integer it knows about) but Windows defines them as unsigned.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682658%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Using only the standard library:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('i', struct.pack('I', 4294966989))
(-307,)
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert positive 32-bit integer to its [two's complement negative value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement):

```
>>> 4294966989 - (1 << 32) # mod 2**32
-307
```

As [@Harry Johnston said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842166/how-to-deal-with-negative-numbers-that-returncode-get-from-subprocess-in-python#comment44103963_27842259), Windows API functions such as `GetExitCodeProcess()` use unsigned 32-bit integers e.g., `DWORD`, `UINT`. But `errorlevel` in `cmd.exe` is 32-bit *signed* integer and therefore some exit codes (> 0x80000000) may be shown as negative numbers.