# Subprocess in Python 3.7 returning different (incorrect?) return code compared with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess, return-code

Some help with a Python 2.7 / 3.7 return code difference in 'subprocess' would be appreciated.

I'm updating some code so that it produces the same output with both Python 2.7 and Python 3.7.

The code runs an external program using 'subprocess' and reads the program's return code. If the external program runs for more than a specific time, it kills itself and returns a return code of '-1'. When the external program is run in a Command Prompt the return code is '-1', as below,:

> C:> test.exe -itest.cmd test.stl > null
>
> *C:> echo %ERRORLEVEL%*
>
> ***-1***

I can run the command using subprocess in Python as below (I've also run it with os.system *just as a comparison*):

```
import os, sys, subprocess

print("\nOutput for Python version: " + sys.version.split("(")[0])

cmd = "test.exe -itest.cmd test.stl > null"
p_input = cmd.split()

p = subprocess.Popen(p_input, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()
p_rc = p.returncode
print("subprocess return code :" + str(p_rc))

os_rc = os.system(cmd)
print("os.system return code :" + str(os_rc))
```

When I run the code with Python 2.7 I get the 'expected' return code:

> *Output for Python version: 2.7.16*
>
> *subprocess return code :**-1***
>
> *os.system return code :**-1***

When I run the code with Python 3.7 I get a different return code for subprocess (but not for os.system):

> *Output for Python version: 3.7.9*
>
> *subprocess return code :**4294967295***
>
> *os.system return code :**-1***

Is this different result expected? Whether it is, or not, how can I get my desired return code of '-1' with Python 3.7?

Running Python 2.7.16 / 3.7.9 on Windows 10

Thanks in advance :-)

Nick

Comment: That's an integer overflow. Now the question is, how to work around that (and possibly: why is this the case)?

Comment: Process exit codes are 8-bit unsigned integers.  -1 wasn't a valid value in the first place.

Comment: Hmm, then 4294967295 is also not valid, since that's 32 bit unsigned integer. And Python 3 is able to work with arbitrarily large integers, so it's some underlying subprocess (C) code?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842166/how-to-deal-with-negative-numbers-that-returncode-get-from-subprocess-in-python

Comment: It looks like return codes for processes in windows can be negative.

Comment: Note that the documentation for subprocesses indicate the following for `.returncode`: "
returncode:  Exit status of the child process. If the process exited due to a signal, this will be the negative signal number."

Comment: @9769953 The quoted documentation about negative signal number is missing an importat part: **"... (POSIX only)"**

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I think we've established that Windows can have negative exit codes, so I would expect subprocess to return the correct Windows exit code. Given that it worked as expected in 2.7, Is this a bug in subprocess in 3.7?

Comment: I think my problem was that I thought it was returning an incorrect value, whereas I think it's returning a correct value, but as an unsigned 32-bit integer. This can be converted to the 'correct' signed 32-bit integer - see the 'answer' for this.

Answer (score 0):

***subprocess.returncode*** now (since 3.3) returns an UNSIGNED 32 bit integer, so the returned value isn't incorrect - just not a signed 32 bit integer. To see negative return codes, the answer needs converting to a SIGNED 32 bit integer. This can be done by adding the following to the above code:

```
import ctypes
...
# get signed value return code in Python 3.*
p_rc = ctypes.c_int32(p_rc).value
print("SIGNED return code  :" + str(p_rc))
```

This gives the following output for Python 3.7:

> Output for Python version: 3.7.9
>
> subprocess return code :**4294967295**
>
> SIGNED return code  :**-1**
>
> os.system return code :-1

Other ways of doing the same (thanks to
kknechtel on discuss.python.org)...
With struct:

```
import struct
...
p_rc = struct.unpack('i', struct.pack('I', p_rc))[0]
```

Or:

```
p_rc = (p_rc - (1 << 32)) if (p_rc >= (1 << 31)) else p_rc
```