# COPY command - unexpected results in STDERR redirection inside a .BAT file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, error-handling, copy, stderr

I am trying to log each file transfer using **`COPY`** command and the redirect **`STDERR`** handle in the following `.BAT` file:

```
Copy /Y FileExist01.txt NewFile01.txt 2>CopyError.log
Copy /Y NoFile02.txt NewFile02.txt 2>>CopyError.log
Copy /Y FileExist03.txt NewFile03.txt 2>>CopyError.log
Copy /Y NoFile04.txt NewFile04.txt 2>>CopyError.log
```

- **`FileExist##.txt`** are files that I know exist *(verified path and

  filename)*
- **`NoFile##.txt`** are files that I know do not exist to test the
  `STDERR` redirect on error *(`2>>CopyError.log`)*

I was expecting to see `2` error lines in the **`CopyError.log`** to show `"The system cannot find the path specified."` but instead **`CopyError.log`** is empty.

Comment: Unfortunately, `Copy` doesn't output that message as StdErr. Previously `XCopy` was offered as an alternative. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8219040) for more information.

Comment: @Compo - Thank you for the prompt explanation. I also wanted to upvote both your answer and John Rocha's, and accept both  but could not see anything in this layout to do so. Again thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `Copy` doesn't output that message as `StdErr`.

Previously `XCopy` was offered as an alternative. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8219040) for more information, however here's a quick idea for you:

```bat
(   Copy /Y "FileExist01.txt" "NewFile01.txt"
    Copy /Y "NoFile02.txt" "NewFile02.txt"
    Copy /Y "FileExist03.txt" "NewFile03.txt"
    Copy /Y "NoFile04.txt" "NewFile04.txt"
)|FindStr /VRC:"^ ">"CopyError.log"
```

Now, as with your intended method, this will not tell you which of the commands actually output the message. If you wanted to do that, you could, I suppose, output the line number:

```bat
(   Copy /Y "FileExist01.txt" "NewFile01.txt"
    Copy /Y "NoFile02.txt" "NewFile02.txt"
    Copy /Y "FileExist03.txt" "NewFile03.txt"
    Copy /Y "NoFile04.txt" "NewFile04.txt"
)|FindStr /VRNC:"^ ">"CopyError.log"
```

Here, the error should be prepended with the number, in this case:

```bat
2:The system cannot find the file specified.
4:The system cannot find the file specified.
```

You will at least then be able to see that it was your `2`nd and `4`th copy commands which failed.

Comment: I learned another new way today thanks to you. This line number could help me investigate the errors. Also, I experimented with *XCOPY* as follows and it yielded another possible xref to the errors.
The .BAT content:
`echo F | XCopy Source\FileExist01.txt Dest\NewFile01.txt /Y >XCopy.log 2>XCopyError.log'
'echo F | XCopy Source\NoFile02.txt Dest\NewFile02.txt /Y >>XCopy.log 2>>XCopyError.log`
XCopyError.log shows **File not found - NoFile02.txt**

Thank You!

Comment: Well with `XCopy`, I'd suggest you use this command line `XCopy "Source\FileExist01.txt" "Dest\NewFile01.txt*" /Y>"XCopy.log"` The asterisk will supress the `F`ile or `D`irectory prompt.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the copy command doesn't print that error message to stderr. I know, WTF!?

Here are some quick tests for you to confirm this. Try the following from your command line:

```
dir missing-file.txt
```

and observe

```
>dir missing-file.txt
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is EC0D-D428

 Directory of c:\TEMP

File Not Found
```

Next do it with redirection and observe it works, the error message is placed in the elog.txt file.

```
>dir missing-file.txt
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is EC0D-D428

 Directory of 

File Not Found

>dir missing-file.txt 2> elog.txt
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is EC0D-D428

 Directory of 


>type elog.txt
File Not Found
```

Now, repeat the above but this time with copy, and then as a last experiment, redirect stdout (1) and observe that the message IS redirected then. Showing that copy puts it's error messages on stdout.

```
>copy /y missing-file.txt n
The system cannot find the file specified.

>copy /y missing-file.txt n 2> elog.txt
The system cannot find the file specified.

>copy /y missing-file.txt n 1> elog.txt

>type elog.txt
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: I know right WTF. Thank you for detailed suggestions. I was also messing with **XCOPY** with the expected result.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please use this command. I've tried and somehow it's works on `copy` command, but both success and error are appended to log file.

```
Copy /Y FileExist01.txt NewFile01.txt > CopyError.log 2>&1
Copy /Y NoFile02.txt NewFile02.txt >> CopyError.log 2>&1
Copy /Y FileExist03.txt NewFile03.txt >> CopyError.log 2>&1
Copy /Y NoFile04.txt NewFile04.txt >> CopyError.log 2>&1
```

run `type CopyError.log` to see the results.

Reference:
https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html